# Count results after filtering out

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, count

I am using MySQL 5.7 and need to count results after filtering out the data. 
My table structure:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+
| id | metakey | metaval | tour_id |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 |       4 |      15 |       1 |
|  2 |       4 |      18 |       1 |
|  3 |       4 |      23 |       1 |
|  4 |       4 |      19 |       2 |
|  5 |       4 |      23 |       2 |
|  6 |       4 |      25 |       2 |
|  7 |       4 |      27 |       3 |
|  8 |       4 |      29 |       3 |
|  9 |       3 |       5 |       1 |
| 10 |       2 |       6 |       1 |
| 11 |       3 |       5 |       2 |
| 12 |       2 |       6 |       2 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

1. metakey -> is something predefined, like 4 for countries,
2. metaval -> is real data id, for example country id

Let's say I selected rows by the following query:

```
SELECT tour_id 
from metas 
WHERE (metakey, metaval) IN ((3, 5), (2, 6)) 
group by tour_id 
having COUNT(tour_id) = 2;

+---------+
| tour_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       2 |
+---------+
```

Now I need to extract a number of tours for each country (country meta key is 4) of that resultset.

Expected result:

```
|-----------|---------|
|country_id |  count  |
|-----------|---------|
|    15     |   1     |
|-----------|---------|
|    18     |   1     |
|-----------|---------|
|    19     |   1     |
|-----------|---------|
|    23     |   2     |
|-----------|---------|
|    25     |   1     |
|-----------|---------|
```

I wrote a query which returns a correct resultset, but it took 0.0231 seconds. Number of rows in table: 35036

```
SELECT metaval, count(tour_id) as numberOfTours
from metas2
where tour_id in ( SELECT tour_id
                   from metas2
                   WHERE (metakey, metaval) IN ((3, 5), (2, 6))
                   group by tour_id
                   having COUNT(tour_id) = 2 ) 
      AND metakey = 4
GROUP BY metaval

+---------+---------------+
| metaval | numberOfTours |
+---------+---------------+
|      15 |             1 |
|      18 |             1 |
|      19 |             1 |
|      23 |             2 |
|      25 |             1 |
+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does anyone have tips to improve performance?

Comment: @Lennart, I don't really have a clue about how to redesign it. Because the main table has lots of columns which stores multiple foreign keys. Please have a look at my other question regarding the same topic: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233360/proper-database-structure-for-storing-multiple-foreign-keys

Comment: @Lennart, I have a `tours` table which has lots of multiple foreign keys type of columns. Have a look please: https://imgur.com/a/V39MEDA like locations, countries, themes and etc. I must be able to filter them like `SELECT * FROM tours WHERE countries LIKE '%4%' AND highlights LIKE '%14%'`.  But I know that using like query is not good from the performance perspective, that's why thought maybe meta table might work better. However, like query worked a lot better than meta table select.

Answer (score 1):

Test:

```
SELECT metaval, COUNT(DISTINCT tour_id) 
FROM metas, ( SELECT tour_id 
              FROM metas 
              WHERE (metakey, metaval) IN ((3, 5), (4, 6)) -- or (2, 6) ?
              GROUP BY tour_id 
              HAVING COUNT(tour_id) = 2 ) tours 
WHERE metas.tour_id = tours.tour_id
GROUP BY metaval
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using MySQL 8, "row constructors" performs poorly.  The following may help:

```
WHERE metakey IN (3,4)
  AND metaval IN (4,6)
  AND (metakey, metaval) IN ((3, 5), (4, 6))
```

Together with

INDEX(metakey, metaval, tour_id),
   INDEX(metaval, metakey, tour_id)

The Optimizer should pick the better index based on statistics.
I included `tour_id` to make each index "covering"; this gives another small performance boost.